# How can I get hollow square bullets in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, symbols, bullets

[image: Code render MWE]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{Minimum Working Example}
\author{Minimally Working Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{Pan-Global Institute of Checklists}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
        \frametitle{Hollow Square Bullets?}

            I would like some hollow, square bullets, please, as one might have on a checklist. Something like the \verb|\square| symbol, $\square$ \\
            If this were a checklist, I would like to give that impression to the viewers:
    
            \begin{itemize}
                \item {Item one}
                \item {Item two}
                \item {Item three with sub-items}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item {Sub-item one with sub-items}
                            \begin{itemize}
                                \item {Sub-sub-item one}
                                \item {Sub-sub-item two}
                            \end{itemize}
                        \item {Sub-item two}
                    \end{itemize}
                \item{Item four}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{$\square$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{$\square$}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{$\square$}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\title{Minimum Working Example}
\author{Minimally Working Author}
\date{\today}
\institute{Pan-Global Institute of Checklists}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile=singleslide]
        \frametitle{Hollow Square Bullets?}

            I would like some hollow, square bullets, please, as one might have on a checklist. Something like the \verb|\square| symbol, $\square$ \\
            If this were a checklist, I would like to give that impression to the viewers:
    
            \begin{itemize}
                \item {Item one}
                \item {Item two}
                \item {Item three with sub-items}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item {Sub-item one with sub-items}
                            \begin{itemize}
                                \item {Sub-sub-item one}
                                \item {Sub-sub-item two}
                            \end{itemize}
                        \item {Sub-item two}
                    \end{itemize}
                \item{Item four}
            \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find this document: https://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf a real lifesaver for beamer customization...

Comment: @Rmano Indeed! I love this overview, too! I recommend it so often